# How could the Gitlab CI runner knows the build failed

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

CI runner - Ubuntu
Executor  - shell

somebody just asked me
How could the Gitlab CI runner knows the build failed ?

I mean
like my java project, sometimes the CI runner failed caused by compile error.
But how did the runner know there was an error happened ?

Is that because runner caught some exception from the shell ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the build command in the *.gitlab-ci.yml* script returned an exit status other than zero.